# How to stretch sidebar in flexbox while having footer and a main content that is not filled?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6E9e.jpg

I want the right sidebar to stretch the footer. Here is my markup:

```
<header>
    Fixed position header
</header>

<main>
    <article>
        <form method="post" class="row">
            <div class="col-l-2 padding-20">
                Table here
            </div>

            <div class="col-l-2 sidebar">
                Checkout stuff here
            </div>
        </form>
    </article>
</main>

<footer>
Footer here
</footer>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 80px /* header height: 80px */
}

main {
    flex: 1;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.col-l-1 {
    flex: 1;
}

.col-l-2 {
    flex: 2;
}

.padding-20 {
    padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

div, article { display: block; }
```

I didn't add vendor prefixes here for readability. The min-height and flex model in the body is to make the footer to stick to the bottom. I don't mind if the table/cart area also stretches. All I need is to make the sidebar go min-height: 100% and to not to push the footer to the bottom but instead stretch till it touches the footer, which is at the bottom. I know it sounds crazy but using `main { flex: 1}` was able to put the footer at the bottom and all I need is to make the row class min-height 100% height of `main`.

EDIT: [Pen/Fiddle](http://codepen.io/gasim/pen/JYPqqQ?editors=110)

Comment: Have you tried to set the height of sidebar to minimum 100% ?
'.sidebar {background: #f8f8f8;min-height:100%}'

See if it works!

Comment: Just tried it with no luck

Comment: oh.! Could you add fiddle? It will be helpful.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main should have `display: flex` too and div, article and form should have `display: flex` and `flex: 1`

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 80px /* header height: 80px */
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.col-l-1 {
    flex: 1;
}

.col-l-2 {
    flex: 2;
}

.padding-20 {
    padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

div, article, form { display: flex; flex:1 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1rLzf95d/

Answer (score 0):

if you add a height to your .row class it will stretch its children to the same height. For example `.row { display: flex; min-height: 100vh; flex-direction: row; }`

Comment: that doesn't work properly because it makes minimum height, the height of the viewport, not the height of the parent